# Getting a large amount of data from standalone Neo4j db into an embedded Neo4j db?

Tags: neo4j

We have a significant, though not huge, amount of data loaded into a stand-alone Neo4j instance via the browser and we need to get that data into the embedded instance in our app.  I tried dumping the data to cypher (a 600kb file) and uploading it to our app to execute, that gets stack overflow errors.

I'm hoping to find an efficient way of doing this with the Java API so that we can do it again on other developers' machines.  This is test data for development but it was entered, with significant effort, and we'd rather not redo all that.

Here's a silly question. Can we just copy the data files from the stand-alone db to the embedded?

Comment: yes, you can just zip up the data directory and copy it around to all of the targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @Dave_Bennett mentions in his comment you can copy over the graph.db folder. Embedded and standalone use exactly the same binary format.

If you want to copy over programmatically, I suggest going with the batch inserter API, see http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/batchinsert.html.

There a great tool for copying over datastores at https://github.com/jexp/store-utils which might give some hints as well.